# What if iOS purchase receipt verification failed?

Tags: ios

The iOS purchase receipt server verification usually works like this:

1. User purchase on iPhone
2. Your app sent the purchase recipt to server
3. Server receive the recipt and send it to Apple to verify
4. Server gets the verify results from Apple  .
5. Server sents the verify result to app

BUT what if only Step 1 is successful? For example, The app can't send request to the server in Step 2 or app can't get response from server in Step 5.
The problem is user already paid. What is the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: I disallow purchases when there is no internet connection. Of course, the signal may 'die' right after the transaction is completed and before contacting the server... A small window of risk.

Comment: I don't know how things work, but from the description, I think the purchase is only valid (money is paid) after step 3. As for step 5, your app can sync with server to check for purchase on resume from inactivity, or continuously retry when there is Internet connection if you haven;t received any verification for a purchase.

Comment: @ranReloaded  Correct. So if this happens, users will definately complain since they paid and gets nothing

Comment: Regardless **when** the transaction is completed (before verifying receipt with Apple or after - I believe its before. Receipt verification is a security bonus for developers to be sure the transaction is valid), as long as the product is non-consummable, you can always restore it for free with -[SKPaymentQueue restoreCompletedTransactions] (user authentication needed)

Comment: This one is not, but others are :)

Comment: You have to check every time, if the connection is available and if the responses is received, you can check on this [xamarin post](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/in-app_purchasing/part_2_-_store_kit_overview_and_retreiving_product_information/) how to handle this.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using **SKPaymentQueue**, then it's easy. All you have to do is to **keep** the **transaction** in SKPaymentQueue until '**step 5**' when you get a success/failure verify result from your server.

If **anything goes wrong** in between step 1 to 5 your app still has access to the transaction in the SKPaymentQueue and can '**reprocess**' it.
The reprocessing of incomplete transactions could kick in at **start of your app** (or some time interval as you prefer).
 Just check SKPaymentQueue to get the **pending/incomplete transactions** and send them to your server (just like '**step 2**'). If your server is still not accessible obviously you won't get to step 5, therefore you don't remove the transaction from the queue and this reprocessing happens **again and again** every time at the next app start (or next queue check time interval) **until** is **fulfilled**.

### Implementation

The implementation is also easy, you need to have a '**transaction observer class**' of **SKPaymentTransactionObserver**.
At app start create an instance of the 'transaction observer class' and that should register itself by call to:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self]
```

Then 'transaction observer class' gets the transactions in method:

```
(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

This method is where you can handle and reprocess all incomplete transactions.

Note that your server must be **idempotent** (i.e able to handle repeated transactions if they already been processed)
Once the server processes and completes **steps 2 to 4**, then it comes to app with success/failure result and that's **the only time** when you want to **remove** that transaction from the queue by call to:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction]
```

And finally give your user the premium feature they purchased at this point.

Comment: Does SKPaymentQueue keep transactions until we finish it, like UserDefault ? 
What if user remove the app ?

Comment: Note that if you have pending auto-renew transaction, you wouldn't be available to purchase that subscription again.