# What if iOS purchase verify failed?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I have the same question as this post :
[What if iOS purchase receipt verification failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287352/what-if-ios-purchase-receipt-verification-failed)

I've read the solution from the post but I still have couple of questions

He said `If anything goes wrong in between step 1 to 5 your app still has access to the transaction in the SKPaymentQueue and can 'reprocess' it.`
What I understand is SKPaymentQueue will save my transactions similar to UserDefault, isn't it ?

So what if I remove my app ? Do I lost app the transactions ?

Comment: “What I understand is SKPaymentQueue will save my transactions similar to UserDefault, isn't it” No, what makes you say that? The payment queue doesn’t store anything on disk.

Comment: So if I validate the purchase fail because of network connection for example, and my connection lost for like 1 day, how can I reprocess it the day after?

Comment: Well, according the source you cited (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23258538/341994), it is still in the queue unless you cleared it.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm wondering that what if I remove my app, is it still in the queue ?

Comment: I understand that, but that has nothing to do with the false idea that it saves the transactions the way UserDefaults does. It doesn't do that.

Comment: Ok, so I understand is:
SKPaymentQueue keeps my transactions in the queue unless I call `finishTransaction` event I terminate my app
but not sure if I remove my app

Answer (score 1):

SKPaymentQueue will not save any transactions to your UserDefaults. However everything is saved into your App Store Receipt except consumable purchases. And if step 5 is not complete, you can always retry verifying receipt from Apple because receipt is stored on device and being reinstalled whenever you reinstall the app.

Are you using any libraries that handle payment process? The basic process of purchasing looks like this:

```swift
func makePurchase(product: SKProduct){
   let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case .purchased:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                handlePurchased()
                break
            case .failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                break
            case .restored:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                handlePurchased()
                break
            case .deferred, .purchasing:
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

func handlePurchased(){
    guard let receiptUrl = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL else {   
       // refresh receipt using SKReceiptRefreshRequest          
       return
    }
    #if DEBUG
        let urlString = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
    #else 
        let urlString = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
    #endif
    let receiptData = try? Data(contentsOf: receiptUrl).base64EncodedString()
    let requestData = ["receipt-data" : receiptData ?? "", "password" : "YOUR_SHARED_SECRET", "exclude-old-transactions" : true] as [String : Any]
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestData, options: [])
    request.httpBody = httpBody
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)  { (data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if data != nil, let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) {
                    // parse your receipt data here, get expires date for subscription or whatever your in-app type is.
            } else {
                // Error occurred while validating receipt.
                // You can ask user to restore completed transactions. 
                // Or restore automatically
                // But make sure you don't make infinite loop
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

You can get full article regarding payment process and receipt validation here: https://blog.apphud.com/swift-tutorial-subscriptions/

I am the author of this blog. It's about auto-renewable subscriptions but purchase and validate process is the same.

Comment: Actually I don't have premium account yet so I just reading document